# (Lua) How do i make my Roblox game detect how many players it has?

Tags: lua, user-input, roblox

I want my Roblox game to know how many players it has in it, such as "This game has 2 players in it." How do i manage that? I looked in the properties of the "Players" menu, and there's no "Amount Of Players" value.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is no property for that. But you can add the following code inside a textlabel.

```
local Textlabel = script.Parent
local players = game.Players:GetPlayers()
local count = #players
Textlabel.Text= "Total players: "..count
```

Comment: I'd usually advise against using string concatenation with numbers. It can lead to `.0`s being added unexpectedly and for decimal numbers the formatting can be different from one implementation to another. Using `string.format` is a much safer way of doing this and it comes with the benefit of allowing padding.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
#game.Players:GetPlayers()
```